# How to format Array of Objects data? (Duplicate values in loop, store in the array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to process Array of Objects and format it as expected.
How can I format array at this time?

Current Objects data

```
array = [
  {
    id: "1",
    answer: "d"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    answer: "a"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    answer: "b"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    answer: "c"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    answer: "b"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    answer: "c"
  }
]
```

I want to format with javascript

```
formatArray = [
  {
    id: "1",
    answer: ["d"]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    answer: []
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    answer: ["a","b","c"]
  }
  {
    id: "4",
    answer: ["b","c"]
  }
]
```

I need to process Array of Objects and format it as expected.
How can I format array at this time?

Comment: note: that's an Array of Objects - it's not JSON (JSON is a **String**) - hint: use `Array#reduce` method

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = array.reduce((acc, value) => { 
    acc[value.id] = acc[value.id] ? acc[value.id] : [];
    acc[value.id] ? acc[value.id].push(value.answer) : [value.answer];
    return acc;
}, {})

let result = Object.entries(data).map(d => ({ id: d[0], data: d[1] }) );
```